# Custom Pagination Not Working Well in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im just New in Wordpress and in PHP .. Now Ive just uploaded a theme in Wordpress. The Problem is The Custom Pagination is not working in Wordpress but works well in USBWebserver. It Only Just show the Same Content

```
<table id="maincon2-Article">


    <?php

        $page2 = $_GET["page2"];

        if($page2 == "" || $page2 == "1"){
            $pages = 0;
        }
        else{
              $pages = ($page2*3)-3;
            }

        $Mobartsql = "Select * from tbl_article ORDER BY `Article_ID` DESC limit 1,3";
        $result4 = $con->query($Mobartsql);
        while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){

            echo    '<tr>

        <td style="width:50%">
                    <a href="'.$row4["Art_Desc"].'"><img src = "https://www.stlouisreviewcenter.com/wp-content/uploads/slrc/'.$row4["Art_pic"].'" id="artpiclink2"/></a>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left:2%" >
                    <h1 id="art-head2" style="color:purple"><a href="'.$row4["Art_Desc"].'">'.$row4["Art_title"].'</a> </h5>
                </td>
        </tr>';

        $results1 = $con->query("Select * from tbl_article ORDER BY `Article_ID` DESC");
        $rows2 = $result1->num_rows/3;
        $rows2 = ceil($rows2);
        }


        echo    '<tr>
                <td><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">';
                for($i=1; $i<=$rows;$i++){
                    ?> <button> <a href="/article/?page=<?php echo $i;?>" style="text-decoration:none;"/><?php echo $i; ?></a> </button>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br/></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
```

Here is the Sample .. Plz Need Help ..

Comment: Can you please define 'not working'? As in it doesn't show the pagination at all, you get to the wrong page, or something else? Do you get any error messages when debugging?

Comment: Opps .. Sorry .. It just show The same Page content